# Why multiple @ComponentScan annotations corrupt my AspectJ transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, aspect

I'm asking this question in continue to the issue I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984315/hibernate-why-is-the-transaction-half-committed).

I got some unexpected behavior when I used AspectJ transactions - some operations were immediately committed to the DB, before that transaction was ended. And therefore they were not rolled back in case of error. When I changed the Advice Mode (`@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`) to  `PROXY` all was working fine.

I found out that I had multiple classes annotated with the `@ComponentScan` annotation, and when I removed all these annotations but one - all was working as expected!

My question is - why?

Comment: I've had similar issue and in my case I didn't find that @componentScan as a possibility. Had to make a workaround.  I suggest you copy code from previous issue to reproduce it, might be a bug in spring. Or at least unclear documentation.